SBT unable to resolve dependency
I have cloned project from cloud repository and facing some sbt issues when trying to run a build.
Checking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml
Checking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last commonSpark / coursierResolutions' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last kpiFormulaSparkEvaluator / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last commonSparkPmCmProcessing / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last commonSpark / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last mbnlSparkPmCmProcessing / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (commonSpark / coursierResolutions) coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 2 error(s) in dependency resolution:
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-core
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-core\maven-metadata.xml
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-api
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-api\maven-metadata.xml
[error] (kpiFormulaSparkEvaluator / ssExtractDependencies) coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 2 error(s) in dependency resolution:
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-core
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-core\maven-metadata.xml
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-api
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-api\maven-metadata.xml
[error] (commonSparkPmCmProcessing / ssExtractDependencies) coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 2 error(s) in dependency resolution:
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-core
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-core\maven-metadata.xml
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-api
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-api\maven-metadata.xml
[error] (commonSpark / ssExtractDependencies) coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 2 error(s) in dependency resolution:
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-core
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-core\maven-metadata.xml
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-api
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-api\maven-metadata.xml
[error] (mbnlSparkPmCmProcessing / ssExtractDependencies) coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 2 error(s) in dependency resolution:
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-core
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-core\maven-metadata.xml
[error]     io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.25.0,1.25.0]:
[error]         not found: C:\Users\eksinvi\.ivy2\local\io.grpc\grpc-api
[error]         wrong checksum: C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc\grpc-api\maven-metadata.xml
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed 7 Aug, 2024 12:13:25 PM
[info] shutting down sbt server

Adding resolvers is also not taking any effect
resolvers ++= Seq("io.grpc" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-core",
  "io.grpc" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-api")


This is multi project build with assembly. I am not able to see the blue square on each respective module as well. Not sure what went wrong.
Earlier this code was working fine.

Maybe the dependency versions are too old and were lost with the sunset of bintray? Try updating them to a newer version.

mvnrepository.com is NOT a repository, it's a website to browse/search other repos. Don't add it to the resolvers.

The artifacts are available in Maven central. Sounds like maybe a corrupted file in your local system? Did you clean your local cache C:\Users\eksinvi\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\io\grpc?

@Gaël J.. this worked like a charm. Thanks.. I wasted my two days trying out several things.
